# RStudio Dataone In .local(x, ...) : Error calling getPackage: The format application is not supported in the getpackage method

Tags: r, rstudio

I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 with `R version 3.3.3` and I am using the package `dataone`

I have been struggling a lot about this error message on RStudio

```
Your login certificate is missing or unreadable. 
You must login again via CILogon using 'dataone::downloadCert(CertificateManager())'
Attempting to call as public user without being authenticated.
Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) :
  Error calling getPackage: The format application is not supported in the getpackage methode
```

I got this error when I run the command:

```
bagitFileName <- getPackage(mn, id=id_case_study, format = "application/zip")
```

To solve this issue I have tried, without succeed:

adding the line `RSTUDIO_DISABLE_SECURE_DOWNLOAD_WARNING=1` into the file /usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site (taken from [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827897-Secure-Package-Downloads-for-R))

`httr::set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )`

I have no clue what it is going on wrong...

Comment: Are you sure `set RSTUDIO... = 1` is valid R syntax? Also, have you tried this code in raw R to exclude possible behavior of Rstudio?

Comment: @Roman thank you! I made a mistake on my question (I will fix it).. I have just added the line ´RSTUDIO_DISABLE_SECURE_DOWNLOAD_WARNING=1´ into the file Rprofile.site